# Reaching a specific Xmlnode from root using XPath with nested indexes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have this xml string that I have to get a specific node

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

//Xml string that has xml content

```
string xmlStr = "<Candidate>
    <Content>
    <DOB>14-Jan-1976</DOB>
    <Employers>
      <Employer>
        <Name>Diane Trucking</Name>
        <Addresses>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>1st Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <City>First City</City>
            <State>FL</State>
            <Zip>12345</Zip>
          </Address>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>1st Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <City>Second City</City>
            <State>FL</State>
            <Zip>12346</Zip>
          </Address>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>3rd Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <City>Third City</City>
            <State>FL</State>
            <Zip>12347</Zip>
          </Address>
        </Addresses>
      </Employer>
      <Employer>
        <Name>Tom Trucking</Name>
        <Addresses>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>4th Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <City>Fourth City</City>
            <State>FL</State>
            <Zip>12348</Zip>
          </Address>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>5th Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <City>Fifth City</City>
            <State>FL</State>
            <Zip>12349</Zip>
          </Address>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine1>6th Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <City>Sixth City</City>
            <State>FL</State>
            <Zip>12340</Zip>
          </Address>
        </Addresses>
      </Employer>
    </Employers>
    </Content>
    </Candidate>";
```

// Create xml Document

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

Navigator for alternative testing

```
        XPathNavigator xPathNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
        XPathExpression expr = XPathExpression.Compile("/Candidate/Content/Employers['1']/Employer['1']/Addresses['1']/Address");
```

Expression to read/Target xml specific xml node

```
        XPathNodeIterator xPathIt = xPathNav.Select(expr);


if(xPathIt == null)
{
```

... xPathIt.Count is also 6

```
}

var xmlNodes1 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Candidate/Content/Employers['1']/Employer['1']/Addresses['1']/Address");

for (int i = 0; i < xmlNodes1.Count; i++ )  
{
```

...xmlNodes1.Count = 6. Returns all 6 address nodes , was expecting 3 nodes of "address" for the specific employers/employer/addresses/address

```
}
```

Both xPathIt as well as xmlNodes1 return 6 "Address" elements
I expected it to return 3 elements as there are 3 addresses for an employer

I wanted to target any element in the xml from root
Also, If I can do this I will be able to update the specific element.

Appreciate the help 
Thank you

Comment: Can you please show XML in your sample instead of HTML-encoded text? Also try to provide complete sample, not set of random lines - item would make question much more readable. Side note - while editing drop "thank you" text - it is not really adding much details to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the single quotes from your XPath:

```
var xmlNodes1 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Candidate/Content/Employers['1']/Employer['1']/Addresses['1']/Address");
```

should be

```
var xmlNodes1 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Candidate/Content/Employers[1]/Employer[1]/Addresses[1]/Address");
```

Note the single quotes around the number 1 are removed.

The predicate for selecting the first item is `[1]`. Using the predicate `['1']` is ignored by `SelectNodes` so you are getting *all* nodes and not just the first.